# Having trouble with this java code - supposed to print and count number of heads and tails in a random coin toss

Tags: java

So as the title says, I have to use a class file and also a main method java file that calls the class file and prints out the starting coin face, as well as 40 more coin face flips. I also need to have 2 counters that count the number of heads and number of tails. Here is my code for my class file and main method file. The problem I'm having is that whenever I run it, it always prints out that heads has 0 count and tails as 40 counts.

**Class File:**

```
import java.util.Random;

    public class CoinToss 
    {
    private String sideUp;

    public CoinToss()
    {
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int number = randomNum.nextInt();

        if(number%2 == 0)
            sideUp = "heads";
        else
            sideUp = "tails";

        System.out.println(sideUp);
    }

    public void toss()
    {
        Random randomNum = new Random();
        int number = randomNum.nextInt();

        if(number%2 != 0)
        {
            sideUp = "heads";
        }
        else
        {
            sideUp = "tails";
        }

        System.out.println(sideUp);
    }

    public String getSideUp()
    {
        return sideUp;
    }

    }
```

**Main Method File**

```
public class CoinTossDemo 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int headsCount = 0;
    int tailsCount = 0;

    System.out.print("The Starting side of the coin is: ");
    CoinToss coin = new CoinToss();
    System.out.println();

    for(int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
    {
        System.out.print("The next side of the coin is: ");
        coin.toss();
        System.out.println();

        if(coin.equals("heads"))
        {
            headsCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            tailsCount++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The amount of heads that showed up is: " + headsCount);

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("The amount of tails that showed up is: " + tailsCount);
}
}
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: if(coin.equals("heads")) should be if(coin.getSideUp().equals("heads"))

Answer (score 1):

Currently you're comparing the `CoinToss coin` object with the String value `heads` and that's why its always going to the `else` part.

I can see that you are setting the result of the current coin toss to `sideUp`(which is a `String`). Thus you need to compare that with the `heads` in the `if`.

```
if(coin.getSideUp().equals("heads")) { // getSideUp() returns the sideUp value
    headsCount++;
} else {
    tailsCount++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your answer to side up property so get that value `coin.getSideUp()`

```
           for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
    {
        System.out.print("The next side of the coin is: ");
        coin.toss();
        System.out.println();

        if (coin.getSideUp().equals("heads")) // use the side up property
        {
            headsCount++;
        }
        else
        {
            tailsCount++;
        }
    }
```